# Markdown4j parsing markdown tables to HTML

Tags: java, html, markdown, markdown4j

I'm making a program for creating markdown and converting to HTML.

I'm using the markdown4j library, as stated in the title, to do the converting. Now here's the problem, I try to make a table using the original markdown standards as following:

```
| column 1 | column 2 |
|----------+----------|
|          |          |
```

This should convert to a HTML table but nothing happens when I parse it.

This is before:

```
#***HELLO!***
~~WORLD!~~
| column 1 | column 2 |
|--|--|
```

and after:

```html
<h1><strong><em>HELLO!</em></strong></h1>
<p><s>WORLD!</s>
<br  />| column 1 | column 2 |
<br  />|&ndash;|&ndash;|</p>
```

Does any of you know why markdown4j is not parsing the table correctly, and if so, how do I fix this?

Comment: The reason markdown4j does not parse your table correctly, appears to be because it does not use that syntax: http://code.google.com/p/markdown4j/#Implementation_of_tables

Comment: @Jongware Thanks for the fast response. With a chance of sounding needy, can you make a very simple code example of making this table?
Another thing as, is there a way to make a plugin for markdown4j to parse the markdown example I gave?

Comment: 1. There is an example in that link. 2. "A way", surely there is. [Creating your own markdown4j plugin](http://code.google.com/p/markdown4j/#Creating_your_own_markdown4j_plugin) outlines the steps. (Funnily enough from the exact same site again, suggesting you may want to read the entire page.)

Comment: I did read, I know the example is there but implementing it in code is the thing, say, I have a two dimensional string array 2x2, how would I make this a table?

Comment: Ok so, I tried the way its explained in the link you gave me. I get this:
```<hr />
<p>test test
<br  />test test</p>
```

Comment: FYI, the original implementation of Markdown [doesn't support tables unless you use HTML tags](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the info, I'm sorry that I've missed that while researching and reading on markdown. I will look into a workaround myself instead now that I know this, also thanks to the rest of you, the answers you have provided was more than helpful :)

Comment: @Jongware I've tried over and over again, even copied the example directly from markdown4j's page about how to make tables, and it still didn't convert to a table, seems that its impossible to achive.. :/ any help maybe?